# Converting a byte array with range of -128 to 127 to String array

Tags: java, utf-8

I have a function for hashing passwords, that returns a byte[] with entries using the full range of the byte datatype from -128 to 127. I have tried to convert the byte[] to a String using `new String(byte_array, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`. This does return a String - however it can not properly encode negative numbers - hence it encodes them to a "�" character. When comparing two of those characters using: `new String(new byte[]{-1}, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).equals(new String(new byte[]{-2}, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))` it turns out the String representation for all negative numbers is equal as the expression above returns true. While this doesn't fully ruin my hashing functionality as the hash of the same expression will still always yield the same result, this is obviously not what I want as it increases the chance of two different inputs yielding the same output drastically.

Is there some easy fix for this or any alternative idea how to convert the byte[] to a String? For context I want to use the String to later write it to a file to store it in a file and later read it again to compare it to other hashes.

**Edit:** After a bit of trying around with the tips from the comments my solution is to convert the byte[] to a char[] and add 128 to every value. The char array can then easily be converted to a String or be written to a file directly (byteHash is the byte[]):

```
char[] charHash = new char[byteHash.length];
for(int i = 0; i < byteHash.length; i++){
    charHash[i] = (char) (byteHash[i]+128);
}
return new String(charHash);
```

I do not really like the solution but it works.

Comment: The bytes of the hash don't represent characters in *any* encoding, much less UTF-8. Trying to display them as characters or treat them as a string doesn't make any sense. The usual thing to do if you want to make it human-readable is to build a string where each byte is treated as an unsigned value between 0 and 255, and converted to two characters using base 16.

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HexFormat.html for an easy way to convert a byte array into a hex string and vis versa.

Comment: @Shawn how would your move the range from -128/127 to 0/255. Other than in c++ I think java doesn't support unsigned data types. I am not necessarily looking for a human-readable String but for something I can write to and read from a file to later compare it to a new hash.

Comment: You can write and read arrays of bytes with OutputStream and InputStream methods (but not Writer/Reader because you're working with binary data, not text).

Comment: @BillMüller - *how would your move the range from -128/127 to 0/255*   for each byte value b,  the value is `((int)b) & 255`.

Comment: @Shawn thank you that solves my problem
@passer-by so you mean I should convert the byte[] to an int[] and then do +128 for every value? As far as I know `new String()` doesn't support int as an input type,
@Darkman I am not exactly sure where you are going. My byte[] array has negative numbers and as I know (or found out) UTF-8 doesn't support negative numbers. So what are you suggesting?

Comment: @Bill I meant that you cannot convert random bytes to UTF-8 or other encodings and expect them to be valid characters. That's the reason it is called encoding. A better encoding for your purpose is US_ASCII. For negative numbers -- thats made up of atleast 2 characters and that's a different story. If you just want to compare 2 arrays, using `Arrays.equals()` is probably a better choice.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate solution to this is to use an encoding like hexadecimal (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HexFormat.html) or Base64 (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) to convert an arbitrary byte sequence to a string reversibly.